# AssertJ: `ignoringFields` is not ignoring all the provided fields?

Tags: kotlin, assertj

I want to compare two objects using `org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat` from version `3.14.0`:

```
assertThat(getActual())
        .usingRecursiveComparison()
        .ignoringFields("customer", "orders", "\$hashCode", "fragments.parentFields.__typename", "fragments.parentFields.image")
        .isEqualTo(orderForm)
```

When I do so I get the following error:

```
when recursively comparing field by field, but found the following difference:

field/property 'fragments' differ:
- actual value   : Fragments{parentFields=Optional[ParentFields{__typename=OrderForm, id=1, image=Image{__typename=Image, id=71, accuracy=100.0, type=ORDER_FORM, state=AUTOMATIC, value=order form, base64=}}]}
- expected value : Fragments{parentFields=Optional[ParentFields{__typename=ParentFields, id=1, image=Image{__typename=Image, id=123, accuracy=99.99, type=NONE, state=NONE, value=value, base64=base64}}]}

The recursive comparison was performed with this configuration:
- the following fields were ignored in the comparison: customer, orders, $hashCode, fragments.parentFields.__typename, fragments.parentFields.image
- overridden equals methods were used in the comparison
- these types were compared with the following comparators:
  - java.lang.Double -> DoubleComparator[precision=1.0E-15]
  - java.lang.Float -> FloatComparator[precision=1.0E-6]
- actual and expected objects and their fields were compared field by field recursively even if they were not of the same type, this allows for example to compare a Person to a PersonDto (call strictTypeChecking(true) to change that behavior).
```

From my understanding, ignoring all the fileds I added to the `ignoreingFields` function the comparison should be:

```
- actual value   : Fragments{parentFields=Optional[ParentFields{id=1}]}
- expected value : Fragments{parentFields=Optional[ParentFields{id=1}]}
```

And thus it should not fail, it should succeed.

The other ignored fileds (`customer`, `orders`, `\$hashCode`) are getting ignored correctly. So I wonder if there is something wrong with fields of nested objects. But in the javadoc I found:

```
* // assertion succeeds as name and home.address.street fields are ignored in the comparison
* assertThat(sherlock).usingRecursiveComparison()
*                     .ignoringFields("name", "home.address.street")
*                     .isEqualTo(noName);
```

So I think im using it as intended by the API.

Ofcourse I could get around all this by simply doing:

```
assertThat(actual
        ?.fragments()
        ?.parentFields()
        ?.get()
        ?.id()
).isEqualTo(orderForm
        .fragments()
        .parentFields()
        .get()
        .id())
```

But I have many objects which I have to compare like that and which do not have the same super class.
So im going to create something like:

```
fun assertCommons(actual: Any, expected: Any) {
    assertThat(actual)
        .usingRecursiveComparison()
        ....
}
```

So back to the question: What goes wrong with ignoring these fields?

**EDIT**

Since `parentFields` is an optional:

```
...
.ignoringFields("customer", "orders", "\$hashCode", "fragments.parentFields.get().__typename", "fragments.parentFields.get().image")
...
```

```
field/property 'fragments' differ:
- actual value   : Fragments{parentFields=Optional[ParentFields{__typename=OrderForm, id=1, image=Image{__typename=Image, id=71, accuracy=100.0, type=ORDER_FORM, state=AUTOMATIC, value=order form, base64=}}]}
- expected value : Fragments{parentFields=Optional[ParentFields{__typename=ParentFields, id=1, image=Image{__typename=Image, id=123, accuracy=99.99, type=NONE, state=NONE, value=value, base64=base64}}]}

The recursive comparison was performed with this configuration:
 - the following fields were ignored in the comparison: customer, orders, $hashCode, fragments.parentFields.get().__typename, fragments.parentFields.get().image
 - overridden equals methods were used in the comparison
 - these types were compared with the following comparators:
 - java.lang.Double -> DoubleComparator[precision=1.0E-15]
 - java.lang.Float -> FloatComparator[precision=1.0E-6]
 - actual and expected objects and their fields were compared field by field recursively even if they were not of the same type, this allows for example to compare a Person to a PersonDto (call strictTypeChecking(true) to change that behavior).
```

With `value` instead of `get()`

```
...
.ignoringFields("customer", "orders", "\$hashCode", "fragments.parentFields.value.__typename", "fragments.parentFields.value.image")
...
```

```
when recursively comparing field by field, but found the following difference:

field/property 'fragments' differ:
- actual value   : Fragments{parentFields=Optional[ParentFields{__typename=OrderForm, id=1, image=Image{__typename=Image, id=71, accuracy=100.0, type=ORDER_FORM, state=AUTOMATIC, value=order form, base64=Optional[]}}]}
- expected value : Fragments{parentFields=Optional[ParentFields{__typename=ParentFields, id=1, image=Image{__typename=Image, id=123, accuracy=99.99, type=NONE, state=NONE, value=value, base64=Optional[base64]}}]}

The recursive comparison was performed with this configuration:
- the following fields were ignored in the comparison: customer, orders, $hashCode, fragments.parentFields.value
- overridden equals methods were used in the comparison
- these types were compared with the following comparators:
  - java.lang.Double -> DoubleComparator[precision=1.0E-15]
  - java.lang.Float -> FloatComparator[precision=1.0E-6]
- actual and expected objects and their fields were compared field by field recursively even if they were not of the same type, this allows for example to compare a Person to a PersonDto (call strictTypeChecking(true) to change that behavior).
```

Comment: `parentFields` is an `Optional`, so I would expect your ignoring-string-chain to look like `fragments.parentFields.get().__typename`

Comment: True, its an optional. I added the outcome to my question. It leads to the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"fragments.parentFields.get().__typename"` is not a valid declaration for what you intend to do. when specifying `"a.b.c"` what AssertJ it going to do is try finding `getA().getB().getC()` or `a.b.c` or nay combination of field/getter (like `getA().b.getC()`.

Specifying `fragments.parentFields.get()` is not going to work as there is no field named `get()`. Try using `value` instead as this is the field returned by `get()` (AssertJ can read private fields).

Comment: So: `.ignoringFields("customer", "orders", "\$hashCode", "fragments.parentFields.value")` also doenst work at all, same error message.

Comment: Alright, can you raise an issue in https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues ideally with a reproducible test case so that we can investigate it?